# MediaController on Custom Adapter is not showing

Tags: android, custom-adapter, mediacontroller

In my custom adapter there are several Text View and two buttons. One is Play and another one is Favorite button. Pressing Play button should play an audio file stored in raw folder and it should also show the media controller with Start, Pause, Forward etc buttons. Here is my custom adapter code.

```
package com.codetrio.alquran.com.codetrio.alquran.util;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.codetrio.alquran.R;
import com.codetrio.alquran.db.AudioFileDataSource;
import com.codetrio.alquran.db.ChapterDataSource;
import com.codetrio.alquran.model.AudioFile;
import com.codetrio.alquran.model.Chapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChapterListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chapter> implements 
MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, View.OnClickListener,
    MediaController.MediaPlayerControl{
ArrayList<Chapter> arabicChapters;
ArrayList<Chapter> banglaChapters;
Context mContext;
private int lastPosition = -1;
MediaPlayer mp;
private MediaController mediaController;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

ChapterDataSource dataSource;
AudioFileDataSource audioFileDataSource;
AudioFile audioFile;
Chapter chapter, chapterBangla;
MyHttpAction myHttpAction;
LinearLayout linearLayout;

@Override
public void start() {
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    mp.pause();
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return mp.getDuration();
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mp.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int i) {
    mp.seekTo(i);
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mp.isPlaying();
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    try{
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(linearLayout);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mediaController.setEnabled(true);
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "here...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mediaController.show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "not playing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView tvChapterNo;
    TextView tvChapterNameBangla;
    TextView tvChapterName;
    TextView tvRevealedAt;
    TextView tvTotalVerse;
    Button btnPlay;
    Button btnFavorite;
    LinearLayout linerLayout;
}

public ChapterListAdapter(ArrayList<Chapter> arabicChapters, ArrayList<Chapter> banglaChapters, Context context){
    super(context, R.layout.chapter_item, arabicChapters);
    this.arabicChapters = arabicChapters;
    this.banglaChapters = banglaChapters;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int position=(Integer) view.getTag();
    Object object= getItem(position);
    Chapter chapter=(Chapter)object;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // Get the data item for this position
    chapter = arabicChapters.get(position);
    chapterBangla = banglaChapters.get(position);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.fatiha);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaController = new MediaController(mContext);

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chapter_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.tvChapterNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvChapterNo);
        viewHolder.tvChapterNameBangla = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvChapterNameBangla);
        viewHolder.tvChapterName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvChapterName);
        viewHolder.tvRevealedAt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRevealedAt);
        viewHolder.tvTotalVerse = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalVerses);
        viewHolder.btnPlay = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        viewHolder.btnFavorite = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);
        viewHolder.linerLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.forMediaController);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.forMediaController);

        viewHolder.btnFavorite.setTag( chapter.getId() );

        view=convertView;

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        view=convertView;
    }

    viewHolder.tvChapterNo.setText(Integer.toString(chapter.getId()));
    viewHolder.tvChapterNameBangla.setText(chapterBangla.getChapterName());
    viewHolder.tvChapterName.setText(chapter.getChapterName());
    viewHolder.tvRevealedAt.setText("Mecca");
    viewHolder.tvTotalVerse.setText("আয়াত সংখ্যা - "+Integer.toString(chapter.getTotalVerses()));

    viewHolder.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            chapter = arabicChapters.get(position); //re initializing otherwise sometimes get previous state
            chapterBangla = banglaChapters.get(position);
            audioFileDataSource = new AudioFileDataSource(getContext());
            audioFile = new AudioFile();
            audioFileDataSource.open();
            audioFile = audioFileDataSource.getAudioFileByChapter(chapter.getId());
            audioFileDataSource.close();
            if(audioFile.getFilePathLocal() != null){

            }else{
                File file = new File("/data/data/com.codetrio.alquran/"+Integer.toString(chapter.getId())+".mp3");
                if(file.exists()){
                    mp.start();
                }else{
                }
            }
        }
    });
    viewHolder.btnFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            chapter = arabicChapters.get(position); //re initializing otherwise sometimes get previous state
            chapterBangla = banglaChapters.get(position);
            dataSource = new ChapterDataSource(getContext());
            dataSource.open();
            dataSource.setAsFavorite(chapter.getId(), chapterBangla.getId());
            dataSource.close();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Here I'm also sharing the layout codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChapterNo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#DDD000"
        android:text="001"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvChapterNameBangla"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#DDD000"
            android:text="Name of the sura"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvChapterName"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#DDD000"
            android:text="Name of the sura"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRevealedAt"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#DDD000"
        android:text="মক্কায় অবতীর্ন"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotalVerses"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#DDD000"
        android:text="- ০৭ টি আয়াত"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFavorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Favorite"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/forMediaController"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

What could be the cause of not showing the Media Controller? Though I can hear audio file is playing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout @id/forMediaController is empty and defined as "wrap_content", so the layout is 0dp height and not visible.

MediaController "setAnchorView()" method is more generally used to set a view like your root layout of your screen.

In your case you want to add mediaController in each row of your list ? In any case you'd better set an anchorView that contains other elements, like root view of your item view.

> Set the view that acts as the anchor for the control view. This can
>   for example be a VideoView, or your Activity's main view. When
>   VideoView calls this method, it will use the VideoView's parent as the
>   anchor.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html#setAnchorView(android.view.View)

Comment: I've tried to set the height of the LinearLayout as 100dp but it didn't work. Also tried to set a VideoView in that layout and binding it with MediaController but the thing is same. I've tried to set the parent layout(layout for the fragment) which is containing the list view but failed!

If I change the onPrepared method as follows then I get an bad token exception. It gives the following exception
                                                                      android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: But are you sure that when onPrepared() is call, your linearlayout variable is set ? You'd better have your MediaPlayer and MediaController out of your adapter. This is not really the good way to duplicate this in each of getView() calls.

Comment: I was thinking so as you said, I wish to place MediaPlayer and MediaController in my Fragment class.